# Jittering of CSS translate property animation in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I'm trying to do some CSS translate animation. Unfortunately Firefox doesn't perform well. It looks  a bit choppy. IE11, Edge, Chrome and even Firefox for Android run this animation very smoothly. So what is wrong in my code below?

Note that I have Firefox 49.0.2 64bit and Windows 10.

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: intro 2s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes intro {
    0%   { 
     opacity: 0;
      transform: translate(15px, 15px);
    }
    100% { 
     opacity: 1;
      transform: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```